# PowerDesigner - DDL generation

Tags: oracle, code-generation, ddl, powerdesigner

Where can I customize the output of DDL scripts generated by PowerDesigner?
I want for all columns defined as varchar2 to generate the DDL with char length types.
E.g. VARCHAR2(10 **CHAR**) instead of VARCHAR2(10)

Of course i have the option to modify the physical model, where I can change the data types but i want to avoid to do this for all models and to mitigate at generation time.

Thanks,
Madalin

Comment: I don't think you can. You could edit the Add, and Create item under Column to replace `%DATATYPE%` with some specific template to get this effect, but then it would break the script reverse-engineer.

Comment: On the other hand, if your columns where specified with a domain, you could just replace (in the physical model), the domain data type...

Comment: Or if the problem is with CDM/LDM to PDM generation, you could edit `Script\DataType\AmcdDataType` in the DBMS, to generate `varchar2(%n char)` from `VA%n`.